# Why does getting an attribute with xpath fail?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to get an attribute from an xml using xpath. When I run the code it throws a UE:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Here is my code to get the attribute.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Test.xml");                    
string attrVal = doc.SelectSingleNode("results/access/@Name").Value;
MessageBox.Show(attrVal);
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results date="2013-12-25">
<access Name="My-Name"/>
</results>
```

Looking into that errors details, I have read that it could be protection on the xml file (shouldn't be, I can open in IE). Is the issue my code, or my xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LoadXml` expects the argument to be XML, not a filename:

```
doc.LoadXml("<hello>world</hello>");
```

You wanted the `Load` method:

```
doc.Load("foo.xml");
```